# A specific List View is throwing XsltListViewWebPart error in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

When opening a view from a list, I get an error:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> The "XsltListViewWebPart" Web Part appears to be causing a problem. Specified >argument was out of the range of valid values.
>
> Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page to >temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For more information, >contact your site administrator.

Resetting the list web part from the Web Parts Maintenance Page doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

After reset the list web part, try to run IISReset and check again.

Besides, is it an OOB list view web part? If not, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768411/the-specified-view-is-invalid-in-call-to-limitedwebpartmanager-addwebpart-in-s) similar post. Or delete this list web part in the Web Parts Maintenance Page and add it again.

If the issue exists, create a new view and check again.

You can check the ULS log based on Correlation ID to get more information about your issue.